# Lingo Guess Game

Tags: python, beginner, game

I'm writing a program for a game called "Lingo":

```
def lingo():                
            guesslst = []
            word = list("tiger")          

            while guesslst != word:
                new = []
                guess = raw_input("Enter word: ")
                guesslst = list(guess)
                for x in guesslst:
                    if x in word:
                        for y in word:
                            if x == y:
                                if word.index(y) == guesslst.index(x):
                                    if x not in new:
                                        new.append("[%s]" %x)
                                else:
                                    if x not in new:
                                        new.append("(%s)" %x)
                    else:
                        if x not in new:
                            new.append(x)
                print("".join(new))            
            print("Congradulations you win! The word was %s" %"".join(word))


def main():            
             print("Loading word list from file...")
             print("Welcome to the game, Lingo!")
             lingo()           

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

This is how it should work:

```
Welcome to the game, Lingo!    
Enter word: snake
snak(e)
Enter word: fiest
f[i](e)s(t)
Enter word: times
[t][i]m[e]s
Enter word: tiger
[t][i][g][e][r]
Congradulations you win! The word was tiger
```

How can I improve this code?

Answer (score 2):

**Various details**

The first things caught by my eye are : an akward indentation, a typo in "Congratulations" and the inlined call to main.

Then, in the slightly less visible details, you are missing a whitespace after the operator `%`.

Finally, in the invisible details, you have trailing whitespaces.

After getting this fixed, you have :

```
def lingo():
    guesslst = []
    word = list("tiger")

    while guesslst != word:
        new = []
        guess = raw_input("Enter word: ")
        guesslst = list(guess)
        for x in guesslst:
            if x in word:
                for y in word:
                    if x == y:
                        if word.index(y) == guesslst.index(x):
                            if x not in new:
                                new.append("[%s]" % x)
                        else:
                            if x not in new:
                                new.append("(%s)" % x)
            else:
                if x not in new:
                    new.append(x)
        print("".join(new))
    print("Congratulations you win! The word was %s" % "".join(word))


def main():
    print("Loading word list from file...")
    print("Welcome to the game, Lingo!")
    lingo()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Subtle bug**

At the moment, when the initial `word` contains a duplicated letter ("tigert" for instance), you code does not quite work.

**A matter of preference**

This is purely personal but I do not quite like having to initialise `guesslst` to an empty list only to make the test for the first iteration go fine. I'd rather write something like :

```
while True:
    guesslst = ...
    ...
    if guesslst == word:
        break
```

**Types**

You do not need to convert your original `word` into a list : `for` and `in` will work just as well on a string. Similarly, you do not need to convert the guesses into a list. This makes a lot of code removable :

```
def lingo():
    word = 'tiger'

    #while True:
    #    guess = raw_input("Enter word: ")
    for guess in ['tige', 'monkey', 'a', 'i', 'tigre', 'tiger', 'tigert', 'foo']:
        new = []
        for x in guess:
            if x in word:
                for y in word:
                    if x == y:
                        if word.index(y) == guess.index(x):
                            if x not in new:
                                new.append("[%s]" % x)
                        else:
                            if x not in new:
                                new.append("(%s)" % x)
            else:
                if x not in new:
                    new.append(x)
        print("".join(new))
        if guess == word:
            print("Congratulations you win! The word was %s" % word)
            break
```

**Code organisation**

It can easily be seen than nothing will happen for a given `x` if it is already in `new`. We might as well extract the corresponding logic in a single place :

```
   for x in guess:
        if x not in new:
            if x in word:
                for y in word:
                    if x == y:
                        if word.index(y) == guess.index(x):
                            new.append("[%s]" % x)
                        else:
                            new.append("(%s)" % x)
                        break
            else:
                new.append(x)
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry about the "various details". I'm actually getting the words from a file so I had to delete a whole lot of things and it was quit hard doing so on the editor provided by this site. Thank you though! :) @Josay

Comment: Oh why do you need the white space after the %x? It works fine without it... @Josay

Comment: I doesn't change anything as far as execution is concerned. It is just a matter of style, I wrote a lot more about this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64160/dict-of-names-and-birth-dates-which-prints-with-age-at-birthday-of-current-year/64166#64166 , I'll let you have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I find the logic in your program is a bit convoluted: there's lots of nesting with a lot of different conditionals. Using some list comprehensions, I think it can be simplified:

For starters, let's call the eventual output we'll give back to the user `hint`. This can just be the string made into a list for the moment:

```
hint = list(guess)
```

Now, let's find the places where they've gotten the character correct and it is in the correct spot:

```
correct_indices = [idx for (idx, (x, y)) in enumerate(zip(test_word, guess))
                   if x == y]
```

This can be read as: zip both `test_word` and `guess` together, creating a list of tuples (so, for example, if the guess was "snake", it'd be:

```
 [('s', 't'), ('n', 'i'),('a', 'g'), ('k', 'e'), ('e', 'r')]
```

Then, from that, create an index for each value starting from `0`. Finally, only create the final list from those indices where the two elements of the tuple have equal values, which is exactly when the match in each spot.

A similar bit of code works to find things letters in `guess` that are in the word, but are in the incorrect place:

```
misplaced_indices = [idx for (idx, y) in enumerate(guess) if y in test_word
                     and idx not in correct_indices]
```

From here, it's a simple matter of modifying our `hint` list with the needed `[]` and `()`, and giving input back to the user:

```
    for idx in correct_indices:
        hint[idx] = '[{0}]'.format(hint[idx])
    for idx in misplaced_indices:
        hint[idx] = '({0})'.format(hint[idx])

    print(''.join(hint))
```

The whole thing looks like:

```
test_word = 'tiger'
guess = ''

while guess != test_word:
    guess = raw_input('Enter word: ')
    correct_indices = [idx for (idx, (x, y)) in enumerate(zip(test_word, guess))
                       if x == y]
    misplaced_indices = [idx for (idx, y) in enumerate(guess) if y in test_word
                         and idx not in correct_indices]
    hint = list(guess)
    for idx in correct_indices:
        hint[idx] = '[{0}]'.format(hint[idx])
    for idx in misplaced_indices:
        hint[idx] = '({0})'.format(hint[idx])

    print(''.join(hint))
```

This still has the bug that if you input the same letter 5 times, and that letter is in the word, you'll get erroneous output. For example, `eeeee` will give:

```
 (e)(e)(e)[e](e)
```

To fix this, we'll need to somehow keep track of what we've seen and what is left. To do this, let's use a handy class from the `collections` module called `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
```

Running this over your word gives the output:

```
Counter({'i': 1, 'r': 1, 'e': 1, 't': 1, 'g': 1})
```

Basically, it just builds up a dictionary with each letter mapping to how many times it appears.

We can then write the code as follows:

```
count = Counter(test_word)
for (idx, (x, y)) in enumerate(zip(test_word, guess)):
    if y in count:
        if x == y:
            hint[idx] = '[{0}]'.format(y)
        else:
            hint[idx] = '({0})'.format(y)
        count[y] -= 1
        if count[y] == 0:
            del count[y]
```

The first line we've seen above. Now, for each letter in `guess`, we check if it exists in `test_word` but seeing if it exists in `count`. If it does, we test if it is equal to whatever is in that position in `test_word` or not. Then, we remove it from count, effectively marking it as "already used". If the count for a letter reaches 0, then we remove that letter from `count` as it can no longer be used.